# Variable API reducer for multiple store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to create a structure like this in a react-redux (or hooks + context) application:

1) ONE dynamic component to dispatch different API calls 
2) ONE reducer that can handle the distribution of data fetched and posted in the relative store

More specific explanation:

I make an API post request from a REACT component, that request call my point 1.
My point 1 calls the relative reducer using a variable action type like: {type: `FETCH_${obj}_INIT} 
**The relative reducer store the data in the right store. (this is my critical point)**

I know I can make multiple reducers, It's ok for me, but Is there a way to not have a HUGE reducer with all the API calls? Do I've to make a single reducer for every HTTP request?
I would love to have one single, variable, reducer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your problem is. Please, provide specific examples.

Comment: I need a reducer that can dynamically store datain different stores

Comment: No specific example, no solution

Comment: Man... if I need something variable, how can I provide you a SPECIFIC example?

Comment: SO is for _**specific**_ programming problems. If you can't clarify your specific problem, your question is supposed to be off-topic.

Comment: I described my specific programming problem.